# C# Debugging DLL

Tags: c#, debugging, com

I'm trying to debug a c# Class Library COM DLL that is called from a VB6 app.

I've set the project properties to run the external app and set breakpoints, but the breakpoints are never triggered.

All the breakpoints report that no 'symbols have not been loaded for this document' and that they won't be hit.

I know that the external app is calling my DLL (MessageBoxes are shown) but how do I debug through it?

Thanks

MM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach to the VB6 process after running the VB6 application. Debug>Attach to process. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: This is a pretty lean answer. I gave an upvote but can you include some screen shots on the process

Comment: @AMR Thanks. Provided a link. I think the key was to make him aware of the attach to process concept.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have experienced the followings given below:

```
1. Go to menu build and click on the configuration manager whether it is chosen as debug mode.
2. Check if the your application dll remains the old in the bin folder. If then, remove all files inside debug->bin folder and rebuild your solution again.
3. You need to make sure the .pdb files are in the same location as the dll resides.
4. then place the breakpoint and check weather it triggers.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all  of these comments - appreciated. All are valid solutions although they didn't address my problem. The issue I had was that although my DLL is indeed called by the external program I was running, it was called - indirectly. The external VB6 program late-bound to another VB DLL in which a reference was early bound to MY dll. I resolved the problem by (temporarily) altering the vb apps to ALL early bind to their respective dependencies.